# Adding text around SVG circle creates whitespace below circle

Tags: svg, whitespace

I have created a circle with text around using svg. When the text is added, there is a lot of whitespace below the cirle and i cannot figure out why and how to get rid of the whitespace.

When removing the "Title 2" the whitespace vanishes but i cannot figure out why.

A simplyfied version of the html generating the circle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="da-DK">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>

        <style>
            .square {height:860px; width:860px; visibility:hidden;}
            .canvas {background-color:#ffff00;}
            .canvas svg {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:860px; height:860px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="canvas">
            <img alt="" class="square" src="square.gif" />
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 860 860">
                <g transform="translate(430 430)">
                    <path id="title1" transform="rotate(6)" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 213.79739461516 361.51165134166 A 420 420 0 0 0 420 0" />
                    <text text-anchor="middle"><textPath xlink:href="#title1" startOffset="50%">Title 1</textPath></text>

                    <path id="title2" transform="rotate(66)" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 91.620161386548 409.88504001427 A 420 420 0 0 0 420 0" />
                    <text text-anchor="middle"><textPath xlink:href="#title2" startOffset="50%">Title 2</textPath></text>

                    <path id="title3" transform="rotate(144)" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 213.79739461516 361.51165134166 A 420 420 0 0 0 420 0" />
                    <text text-anchor="middle"><textPath xlink:href="#title3" startOffset="50%">Title 3</textPath></text>

                    <path id="title4" transform="rotate(204)" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 420 0 A 420 420 0 0 1 174.83793274937 381.87916579977" />
                    <text text-anchor="middle" dy="13"><textPath xlink:href="#title4" startOffset="50%">Title 4</textPath></text>

                    <path id="title5" transform="rotate(270)" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 420 0 A 420 420 0 0 1 385.45694278727 166.80211406661" />
                    <text text-anchor="middle" dy="13"><textPath xlink:href="#title5" startOffset="50%">Title 5</textPath></text>

                    <path id="title6" transform="rotate(294)" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 420 0 A 420 420 0 0 1 385.45694278727 166.80211406661" />
                    <text text-anchor="middle" dy="13"><textPath xlink:href="#title6" startOffset="50%">Title 6</textPath></text>

                    <path id="title2" transform="rotate(318)" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 420 0 A 420 420 0 0 1 284.28790726672 309.16077659029" />
                    <text text-anchor="middle" dy="13"><textPath xlink:href="#title7" startOffset="50%">Title 7</textPath></text>
                </g>
            </svg>
            <br>
            Here is a new line inside the canvas.<br>
        </div>
        Here is a new line outside the canvas.<br>
    </body>
</html>
```

The square.gif contains a black square measuring 10x10 px.

[Image showing the problem in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/notwo.png)

[Image showing title 2 removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYW5O.png)

Comment: looks much the same with or without title2 to me.

Comment: Added width and height to .canvas svg, as the html renders very different in IE11 and Chrome. I have the issue in IE11.

Comment: I have added a image to the post showing the problem in IE11.

Comment: Are you talking about the empty section of page below the "...outside the canvas" line?

Comment: Yes, it is the whitespace below "...outside the canvas" line.

Comment: I have added a image how it look with title 2 removed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could tell, there is a bug in IE and by adding "overflow: hidden" to svg the problem is solves.

```
.canvas svg {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:860px; height:860px; overflow: hidden;}
```